# SignalR C# client not connecting with NTLM

Tags: windows-authentication, signalr, ntlm

SignalR 1.0 RC2 aspnet C# client sample. What needs to be done to have that client connect using Windows-authetication to a (IIS 6) hub server that has anonymous login disabled. Is there any sample out there? This is an intranet app which relies on AD user ids. The client will be implemented as a service eventually. Browser based clients work without problems. Any help or clue would be appreciated!

Comment: Try setting connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: As a note we had a similar problem, but it turned out WHEN we were setting the connection credentials was the significant thing. When we had the problem we were creating the connection on demand, and as it happens often in a thread (as a result of various async operations) and so because the Thread the code executed in had no identity CredentailsCache.DefaultCredentials was null. The answer was to grab the credentials at the program start (in the main thread) and inject those as well. Problem solved. Just be aware your thread context when assigning the value!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting

```
connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```